# Using counter/index to cycle through an array of images onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, counter

I am trying to create code that goes through a traffic light sequence when I click the button. I know there are a lot of people having the same problem however none of the solutions they got seem to work - I can only get the first asset (red traffic light) to display on the webpage and when I click the button nothing happens... Maybe I just need my code proof reading and there is something really obvious I've made a mistake on?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>
    <img id="image" src="red.png" style="width:200px">
    <input type="button" onclick="nextpic()" value="change image" >

<script>
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var counter = 0;
var trafficlights = [
    "redamber.png",
    "amber.png",
    "green.png",
    "red.png"
];
function nextpic(){
    counter =counter+1;
    if (counter == trafficlights.length){
        counter = 0;
    }
    image.src = trafficlights[counter];
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code works fine, make sure your code is inside a window.onload function

Comment: Seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/Lm07soon/

Comment: Just to say that you can write your `nextpic` function like this: `function nextpic() {
  image.src = trafficlights[counter];
  counter = (counter + 1) % trafficlights.length;
}` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6epunkkg/)